# Sending a processed video from C# program to C++ program

Tags: c#, .net, c++, streaming, video-streaming

I am capturing video from my webcam and it is processed by a C# program then i want to stream it to a C++ program. this C++ program can be configured to get a video stream from a webcam so is it possible to send/stream my processed video to this program where the C++ program detect that stream as a video which is coming from the webcam.

Thanks !

EDIT : My C# program access the webcam and do some processing. on the other side i have CCV which accepts either input from a webcam or a video file. so i want to send(stream) my processed video to CCV.

Comment: Do you have the source code of both programs?

Comment: @Oded : as karlphillip mentioned it is IPC.

Comment: @karlphillips : C# code is lengthy and i use Community Core Vision as the above mentioned C++ program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could simply overcome my problem using [SplitCam](http://download.cnet.com/SplitCam/3000-2348_4-10500269.html) Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for how to do [Interprocess Communication on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Code Project also has a [great article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/Win32IPC.aspx) about it.

Comment: @Kenshan Ideally, you should have only one program to grab the frames from the camera, process them and do whatever else you might find necessary. Breaking your solution into 2 applications will bring some overhead you might not want at your final solution. By the way, have you heard of OpenCV?

Comment: If you are going to vote down you should add a note explaining why.

Comment: @karlphillip : yes, i am using CCV which uses OpenCV for image processing and i am agree with you but the problem is i don't have much time to hack into CCV code base and write a patch for my needs and i found out i can do that processing part with C# easily (but i am really really new to C#) so, i write the processing part with C#

Comment: @karlphillip, I can't understand when u can use interoperability you suggest Interprocess? you can simply write a com object in c++ and refrence it in C# so you can use both language benefits, Capturing from web cam and doing process and connecting to other application does not need 2 different application. if you are not familiar with c++ its not good to do this suggestion.

Comment: @Keshan I still think you should seriously consider the *standalone* solution since both IPC and interoperability approaches requires more work. This link contains a complete C program (that uses OpenCV) that reads frames from the camera and defines a function to be executed on every frame. It does grayscale conversion of the frames and displays them on a window: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907028/opencv-every-frame-processing/3919216#3919216

Comment: Thank you very much karl however i overcame my problem. appreciate your help.. :)