# OpenCV 'cvQueryFrame' non-blocking on OS X?

Tags: c, opencv, webcam, video-capture, blocking

when I perform a cvQueryFrame on Windows, the API blocks until an image is delivered. On Mac OS X, I am at 100% CPU utilization, while only querying for an image and displaying it in a window. I am at the latest SVN version. Can anyone confirm my experience? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a work-around?

My loop code looks like this:

```
while(key != 'q') {
    if (frame)
        cvShowImage("Live Cam", frame);
    frame = NULL;
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    key = cvWaitKey(10);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just executed a demo application I [presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907028/opencv-every-frame-processing/3919216#3919216) and it uses ~22% CPU, according to *Activity Monitor*. I ran the program on a Macbook Pro 13", with OpenCV 2.1 (**32bits**).

If you pay attention to that code you'll notice that the loop is a little bit different from yours:

```
IplImage* frame = NULL;
char key = 0;
while (key != 27) // ESC
{    
  frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
  if(!frame) 
  {
      fprintf( stderr, "!!! cvQueryFrame failed!\n" );
      break;
  }

  cvShowImage("Live Cam", frame );
  key = cvWaitKey(10);
}
```

Comment: Very weird, but thanks a lot. I probably checked out a wrong version.