# making USB video in Linux

Tags: linux, video, usb

I am working on an embedded device using Linux that will read video, process and modify every frame and then return USB video stream. I don't know how to make USB video from a sequence of frames. Can someone direct me where to start?

Comment: Are you just asking how to create a video stream and send it over USB, or is your the device you're working on a UVC device?

Comment: Did you mean programatically or are you looking for a tool to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/

It shows you how to make video from a sequence of images using ffmpeg and mencoder

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).

There are lots of code around here to show you how to use the library. For instance, take a look at: [OpenCV: process every frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907028/opencv-every-frame-processing/3919216#3919216)